# When the owner of heap data get out of the scope, how does the compile drop it?

Tags: rust

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuMFY.png)

when s1 and s2 get out of the scope, whether rust compile drop the String::from("hello")? if the answer is yes, how does the compile work? the rust official document say only the owner of heap data get out of the scope will be dropped. This make me confusion. because if it is true, there will be a memory leaking.

Comment: There are two distinct variables named `s3`. Both are dropped at the end of `main`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when s1 and s2 get out of the scope, whether rust compile drop the String::from("hello")? if the answer is yes, how does the compile work? the rust official document say only the owner of heap data get out of the scope will be dropped. This make me confusion. because if it is true, there will be a memory leaking.

At the end of the scope, `s1` and `s2` don't own anything (they have been moved-from already so they're irrelevant). However there are two *different* bindings called `s3` (one shadowing the other), which will get dropped:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("s1");
    let s2 = String::from("s2");
    let s3 = s1;
    let s3 = s2;
}
// string "s2" is dropped
// string "s1" is dropped
```

If instead `s3` is *rebound* (updated), then its value is dropped right there just after the rebinding:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("s1");
    let s2 = String::from("s2");
    let mut s3 = s1;
    s3 = s2;
    // string "s1" is dropped
}
// string "s2" is dropped
```